# perl regex dynamic capturing

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to set a dynamic capture unit

```
my $pattern = '`(.*?)`';
$string =~ s{$pattern}{<code/>$1</code>}im;
```

But instead of passing `<code/>$1</code>` directly to replace, i want to store it as a variable (which may defer depending on the type of data i want to capture)

```
my $pattern = '`(.*?)`';
my $replace = '<code/>$1</code>'; #or my $replace = '<code/>$2</code>'
$string =~ s{$pattern}{$replace}im;
```

Comment: You've basically got it here. Replace those single quotes with double quotes to make them work like you want. `'a$1'` != `"a$1"` - there's no interpolation in the first, but there is in the second.

Comment: i dont get it when i use `""` it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this post](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=715622), Jenda offers a solution that may be applicable to your case. It involves creating a sub and then evaluating the sub to a regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = '`(.*?)`';
my $replace = '<code/>$1</code>';
my $code = 'sub {$_[0] =~ s{$pattern}{'. $replace . '}ig}';
my $re = eval $code;

my $string = "Here `is` a string";
$re->($string);

print $string;
```

This prints `Here <code/>is</code> a string`

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If `$replace` is tainted (ie. contains input from the outside world) this is vulnerable to code injection. `$replace = '}; print "Gotcha!\n"; m{'`

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for pointing that out. I failed to mention that and assumed it would come only from an internal source.